# Concentration inequality for Lipschitz Function

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, concentration-of-measure, large-deviation-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $(X_n:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m)_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables and let $L:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be Lipschitz.  Let $\mu_n:=\frac1{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \delta_{X_k}$.  Are there conditions under which:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(|\mathbb{E}_{X\sim\mu_n}[L(X)]-\mathbb{E}_{X\sim Law(X_1)}[L(X)]|\geq t\right)\leq \exp\left(
-t^2
\right),
$$
where $c>0$ is some constant?

Comment: To get either  Hoeffding or Bernstein type inequalities, you normally need boundedness. Is the range of your function all of R?

Comment: @JohnK Yes unfortunately the rance of $L$ is unbounded; so I wasn't sure how to proceed (since the inequalities you mentioned are for bounded RVs)...I was thinking maybe some large deviations-type result?

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question, but if $X$ is Gaussian, then you can show that its image under a $K$-Lipschitz map $L$ exhibits sub-Gaussian concentration: $P(|L(X) - E\, L(X)| \geq t) \leq C\exp (-c t^2 K^{-2})$. I can include a proof if this is what you're looking for. Also, I'm not sure if there is a typo, but aren't the quantities in $\mathbb{P}(\cdot)$ in your question all deterministic?

Comment: I guess the same holds true for any sub-Gaussian RV

Comment: It does not generalize as is to subgaussian random variables: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334335/lipschitz-function-of-independent-subgaussian-random-variables

Comment: Also your bound always hold for large enough $n$ when $L(X)$ has finite variance by the LLN. Maybe you forgot a factor $n$? I would look into empirical process-type concentration inequalities, which do allow for unbounded functions.